# VHDL: using only portion of outport

Tags: vhdl, vivado

I have an entity instantiated that has an out port of 32 bits.  I only need bits 4 through 15 which will go into some signal `s_a`.  I thought I could instantiate it this way but Vivado does not like it:

```
WHATEVER: entity work.example_entity
  port map(
    o_port( 15 downto 4 ) => s_a
  );
```

I know you can do something analogous with in ports and Vivado seems ok with that so long as I set all the bits to something like so:

```
WHATEVER2: entity work.other_entity
  port map(
    i_port( 7 downto 4 ) => ( others => '0' ),
    i_port( 3 downto 0 ) => s_b
  );
```

where `i_port` is an in port and `s_b` is some appropriately sized and typed signal.

Is there some way to only extract a subset of bits from an out port without connecting the entire port to a full-width signal and extracting the bits from that?

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-2008 6.5.6.3  Port clauses "... It is an error if a port of mode in is unconnected (see 6.5.6.3) or unassociated (see 6.5.7.3) unless its declaration includes a default expression (see 6.5.2). It is an error if a port of any mode other than **in** is unconnected or unassociated and its type is an unconstrained or partially constrained composite type. It is an error if some of the subelements of a composite formal port are connected and others are either unconnected or unassociated." The answer is ...no. (This is consistent with your experience and two examples.)

Comment: what does "not like" mean? That's not a very specific error. Does `o_port(3 downto 0 ) => open,` to cover the unused bits help?

Comment: @user_1818839 The error is `not all partial formals of 'o_port' have actual`.  I'll try the `open`.

Comment: @aquaticapetheory that's what I thought, and "open" should take care of it. VHDL tries quite hard to warn about loose ends like this, because they are probable bugs, and "open" says "I meant to do that" (just like my cat when he falls off the windowsill)

Comment: @user_1818839 Doesn't work, unfortunately.  An entire port has to be `open`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like user16145658 said, the answer is "no."  The `open` keyword only works on a whole out port, all bits included, and cannot be used on individual bits.  If you use any of the bits in an out port then they all have to go somewhere.